# Instance variables set in callbacks being set multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two classes, a parent and a child, simplified below.

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :child
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :child

  validates :child, :presence => true
  validates_associated :child
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent

  attr_accessible :third_party_attribute

  before_validation :set_attributes
  validates :parent, :presence => true
  validates :third_party_attribute, :presence => true

  def set_attributes
    if self.third_party_attribute.nil?
      self.third_party_attribute = <MAKE THIRD PARTY FUNCTION CALL>
    end
  end
end
```

When I pass in attributes (including child attributes), and save the `Parent` model instance, I see that my Child validations are being run twice (once for the validation/save of that Child, and once for the `validates_associated` call in the Parent model). That part makes sense.

The problem is that in both of those validation calls, my third party function call is being triggered.  It's like I set the attribute the first time through validation, but then the second time through validation, the object doesn't recognize that its attribute has already been set.  The frustrating part is that there is a real dollar cost associated with calling this third party service, so I can't really make duplicate calls for no reason.

How do I fix this so that the third party call is only being made once, regardless of how many times the object is validated before saving?

Comment: There could be a way to fix this in your controller... can you post the relevant code from your controller action?

Comment: There is no controller action at this point.  The error occurs just in saving in params from the console.

Comment: What are you specifically running in console?

Comment: person = Person.new({<my params hash>})
person.save

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def set_attributes
  if third_party_attribute.nil?
    self.third_party_attribute = <MAKE THIRD PARTY FUNCTION CALL>
  end
end
```

Notice that the condition is `if third_party_attribute.nil?` instead of `self.third_party_attribute.nil?`

Refer [this](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#callback-registration)

Comment: This is already included in the question? And it's unclear how it answers it. You should try and provide an explanatory sentence or two.

Comment: I already have that.  The issue is that it keeps evaluating `third_party_attribute` or `self.third_party_attribute` to nil on each validation before the save.

Comment: I have tried it with and without the `self` reference - the end result is the same.

Comment: Easy way would be to remove the validation for third_party_attribute and call set_attributes on before_save. That way you can avoid calling the method twice and still achieve the same result

Comment: @Vimsha - I can't put it in a before_save callback, or else the child model could be fail to save, but the parent would still save.  It needs to be a validation callback in order to invalidate the parent model on failure.